# SSRS: vertical strip line on category axis

Tags: reporting-services, charts, ssrs-2012

I have a year-on-year line chart as shown below. 
Y-axis is a category axis (month number), not scalar - otherwise I cannot build year-on-year chart. I need a strip line run through specific month. As far as I understand, strip lines are only possible for scalar (number/date) axis.
[image: Line chart]
Questions:
- Is it possible to add strip line to existing chart?
- If not, how to build year-on-year chart with scalar horizontal axis?

Comment: Did you try it? What problem did you have?

Comment: tried bunch of things, even explicitly specified month number as strip width - nothing happened

Comment: Does this guide help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4967641/implementing-target-lines-in-ssrs-column-charts. I know that you have to set up all the properties exactly or it won't appear.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Played around, no progress. Still suppose this is because axis is not scalar

Answer (score 0):

Find the solution - not obvious, though.
Strip line itself still does not appear, but I used it's background colour instead.
[image]